# capybara Rails3 'cannot fill in'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

This is so frustrating that after examining all stackoverflow queries on a related subject, having the tests seemingly pass before, I cannot get this simple thing to line up and pass. It cannot find a label "quality" in a form_for (@price).

```
 And I fill in "good" in Quality
 cannot fill in, no text field, text area or password field with id, name, or label    'price[quality]' found (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
```

My feature (abridged)

```
 Scenario: Adding corn price
  And I fill in "good" in Quality
```

My step (abridged)

```
  When /^I fill in "([^"]*)" in Quality$/ do |text|
   fill_in('price[quality]', :with => text)
  end
```

My form:

```
 <%= form_for (@price), :url => prices_path  do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :quality %><br />
     <%= f.text_field :quality %>
   </div>
```

My source:

```
 <div class="field">
   <label for="price_quality">Quality</label><br />
   <input id="price_quality" name="price[quality]" size="30" type="text" />
   </div>
```

I've tried so many combinations to get it to pass, and I've run out of combinations to try, sam

Answer (score 0):

What about use next:

```
When /^I fill in "([^"]*)" in Quality$/ do |text|
  fill_in('price_quality', :with => text)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. That fails as well, using your exact text above.

Comment: And using variations of the word "quality" in the feature, the grep'd portion in steps also fail as well. I found that in my searches previously, but cannot find again to link.

Comment: The same error occurs when I reorient the feature and step to "And I fill in "Quality" with "good"" Also tried "price_quality" as a field.

Comment: The step above this is "Then I should go to the new price page" which results from coming from a commodity page.